# PHP OOP unable to edit class properties

Tags: php

New to PHP and especially OOP.

I have a class User.php which I am using in login.php.

```
$vars = $user->login($email, $pass)
```

At the moment I am calling the login method as the above, eventually I am going to call an if statment to validate, etc.
At the moment however, I am trying to connect to the DB, pull some information out and add that information to the properties in my class. I can pull the information out (verified by var_dumps of the objects in method login() (vardump of $results), yet for some reason with my current code I cannot update my class properties.

Here is my code

User.php

```
<?php

class User {

public $id, $password, $first_name, $last_name;
private $user_level;
protected static $db_fields = array('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'pass');
protected static $table_name="users";


public function login($email, $pass) {
    global $database;
    $sql = "SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, user_level FROM users WHERE (email='$email' AND pass=SHA1('$pass')) AND active IS NULL LIMIT 1";
    $results = self::find_by_sql($sql);
    if (!empty($results)) {
        $this->setuservars($results);
        return array_shift($results);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
//  return !empty($results) ? array_shift($results) : false;
}


private function setuservars($uservariables) {
    $this->id = $uservariables->id;
    $this->first_name = $uservariables->first_name;
    $this->last_name = $uservariables->last_name;
    $this->user_level = $uservariables->user_level;

    }



public static function find_by_sql($sql="") {
    global $database;
    $results_array = $database->query($sql);
    $object_array = array();
    while ($row = $results_array->fetch_assoc()) {
        $object_array[] = self::instantiate($row);
    }
    return $object_array;
}


public function mysqli_array_escape($arg1){
    global $database;
    foreach ($arg1 as $key => $value) {
        $arg1[$key] = $database->real_escape_string($value);
    }
    return $arg1;
}


private static function instantiate($record) {
    // Could check that $record exists and is an array
    $object = new self;
    foreach($record as $attribute=>$value){
        if($object->has_attribute($attribute)) {
            $object->$attribute = $value;
        }
    }
    return $object;
}


private function has_attribute($attribute) {
    return array_key_exists($attribute, $this->attributes());
}

protected function attributes() {
    // return an array of attribute names and their values
    $attributes = array();
    foreach(self::$db_fields as $field) {
        if(property_exists($this, $field)) {
            $attributes[$field] = $this->$field;
        }
    }
    return $attributes;
}

}



$user = new User();


?>
```

and here is my login.php (I have edited the if statement with to verify the user logged in successfully, i have replaced with "if (1 == 1) {" statement just to help with debugging code.

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

$postdata = $user->mysqli_array_escape($_POST);

//var_dump($user->results);

if (((!isset($_POST['email'])) || ($_POST['email']) == '') || (!isset($_POST['pass']) || ($_POST['pass']) == '') ) {
    //error handling eventually
} else { 
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $vars = $user->login($email, $pass);
    echo $vars->first_name;


    if (1 == 1) {
        echo "you have successfully logged in";
        var_dump($user->id);

    } else { 
        echo "not logged in"; 
    }
}   

}
```

Oh and the current error I am receiving is "An error occurred in script 'F:\internet\www\htdocs\blissoop\classes\User.php' on line 26: Trying to get property of non-object
Date/Time: 4-13-2012 05:01:09"

Comment: In regards to your error @ line 26: Your sql will most likely be returning `user_id` as that's the column name in your DB so then the object you are accessing should be `$uservariables->user_id`

Comment: @aupdo ah nice catch.  deleted bad answer.  didn't notice the scroll.  well then my next advice would be to var_dump $uservariables and see what it contains.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code to "$this->id = $uservariables->user_id;" yet I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @JohnB vardump of uservariables = "Array(1) { [0]=> object(User)#7 (4) { ["id"]=> NULL ["first_name"]=> string(7) "Melanie" ["last_name"]=> string(6) "Janson" ["user_level":"User":private]=> string(1) "1" } }"

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue with help from this question

here was the code that helped : [Get value from Multidimentional Array containing an Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128519/get-value-from-multidimentional-array-containing-an-object).

I have +1'd the answer which helped.

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
$userId = $item->user_id;
//do something with the userId for this item
}
```

I had to loop through the array to be able to get the object's properties.