# Return value when searching for key in array PHP

Tags: php, search, key, multidimensional-array

I tried to get an answer for this in other posts with no luck, hope someone can help me here, i have a multidimensional array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [affectsVersions] => Array ( ) 
        [assignee] => hmontes 
        [attachmentNames] => Array ( ) 
        [components] => Array ( ) 
        [created] => 2012-08-15T05:31:26.000Z
        [customFieldValues] => Array ( 
            [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                [customfieldId] => customfield_10201
                [key] => [values] => Array ( 
                    [0] => 123456
                )
            )
            [1] => stdClass Object ( 
                [customfieldId] => customfield_10004
                [key] => [values] => Array ( 
                    [0] => 30
                )
            )
        )
        [description] => [duedate] => [environment] => [fixVersions] => Array ( )
        [id] => 10228
        [key] => NTP-29
        [priority] => 3
        [project] => NTP
        [reporter] => hmontes
        [resolution] => [status] => 1
        [summary] => case 123456
        [type] => 3
        [updated] => 2012-08-15T05:31:26.000Z
        [votes] => 0
    )
)
```

this is what i get when i do a print_r with the array variable, i need to search and get the value from [key] that would be in this case NTP-29 and keep it in a variable as string.

Comment: What do you mean search and get the value from key? Do you know the key or are you trying to get the key by searching for the value?

Comment: @sberry you're a gentleman and a scholar. I thank you :)

Comment: @JaredDrake yeah, that wasn't fun at all.

Comment: An up-vote for you, for the correct answer.

Comment: [Similar question with answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128519/get-value-from-multidimentional-array-containing-an-object)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the value of an array by the key using $array['keyName'];

But, for you it looks like you just need to go deeper $array[0]['key'];

Comment: It will work.  The toplevel array has only a single numerically indexed element.

Answer (score 0):

Both arrays values and properties of objects can be accessed using associative array syntax.  To get the value of the `key` property in your object within the array you'd do the following, assuming `$array` is a variable containing a reference to your array:

```
$key = $array[0]['key']; // accesses NTP-29 in this case.
```

Here's another way to access the same property, using object property-access syntax:

```
$key = $array[0]->key; // also accesses NTP-29.
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help, i was working late last night and didn't format anything in the question, i do appreciate your help, it worked for me like expected!, great work!.